# git log doesn't work with path unless file is in current directory

Tags: git

I'm using mingw64 on windows 10 and trying to see the git log of a single file. if I cd into the folder containing the file and use

```
git log -- file.txt
```

it works fine. However if I'm in the folder above and try to use any of the following, it just returns nothing

```
git log -- folder/file.txt
git log -- /c/full/path/to/folder/file.txt
git log -- folder\file.txt
git log -- folder\\file.txt
```

I've also tried puting a backslash in front of the '--' but to no avail. exactly the same happens with gitk

Comment: The only way I can reproduce this behavior is at a repository boundary, where one repo worktree is nested under another (as with submodules) and the file is at the top level of the "inner" repository.  If that is your use case, then yes, that occurs.  So what's your question?

Comment: If the current directory a git worktree (has `.git` in it or above) or is `folder` the git worktree (there is `folder/.git`)?

Comment: hmm my folder is several levels down in the working tree. It seems a very simple straightforward case to me which is why i'm so mystified it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the answer. file path arguments are case-sensitive even when the `core.ignorecase` config is true. I was typing the file and folder names in lower case which seems to work with 'ls' and other mingw commands but not with git.